# customized ISO with ubuntu 23.10

Tags: live-cd, minimal-install

"I utilized Ubuntu 23.10 to create a customized ISO with the intention that, upon burning it to a USB drive, it will automatically launch my designated startup application. However, everything is functioning as expected except for an unwanted notification prompting the installation of the Ubuntu version. How can I prevent this installation from appearing?"

---

[image]

I am creating a customized iso based on ubuntu_23.10,and when I boot it  only my application should be displayed on window and nothing else.In background my-startup application is running but the white window that comes is unwanted.
That white unwanted pop-up is basically for installation of ubuntu. which give us option to try or install ubuntu. I want that try option. How I can do it.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please provide more details on what exactly shows up and is unwanted. Provide some screenshots as well so potential respondents know exactly what you are taking about.

Comment: ehm. you need to install onto an USB (you need TWO of them to use the 2nd to make a persistent install. Then that USB will boot into the installed Ubuntu and you can use 'startup applications' to start your app. You can not do this from the USB installer. That one will always want to do "install" or "try".

Comment: "I started with the official Ubuntu 23.10 ISO, mounted it in a directory, and then entered a chroot environment to perform the installation. I added my own applications to the environment and subsequently unmounted it. After that, I created a customized ISO with these modifications and burned it to a USB drive. When I booted from the USB, everything worked perfectly, except for the white window (ubuntu-desktop-installer) screen that prompts for language selection, the choice between trying or installing Ubuntu, and address information. I'm looking for a way to skip this initial setup screen."